# Multiple dynamic interdependent comboboxes in an userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to vba. I am trying to create an userform with multiple combo boxes where the data has to be loaded from table columns and I need only the unique values. Also I need to link or make dependencies from one combo box to the other as in when I select a value from a combo box the others should contain only the unique options available in the other corresponding columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Ufr.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sGOE.png)

I have added the picture of my userform and the headers of the table. so the combo boxes related the headers are:

```
Source --> Fiche Source
Division --> Division
Name of Project --> Nom Projet
N° Maco --> Projets en cours (It should automatically populate a unique number related to Name 
of project)
Status --> Statut Projet
Client --> Client
Resp Pole --> Pole
RFC --> RfC détail
Month --> Mois
```

And finally the Reset All button should clear all selected items, and Filter Selection button should filter the table based on values selected in the combo box or boxes.

Could anyone please help me to build this?

Thank you !!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, SO is not a code writing service so you have to make your own research and attempt then ask a question when you have a problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.